# CSS Using your own font

Tags: css

Alright so I'm trying to use a font I found on the internet. I followed W3schools on how to do it but it's not working. What I have right now is...

```
HTML:
<a href="link.html" class="links">Link</a>

CSS: 
@font-face {
     font-family: myFirstFont;
     src: url(simplifica.ttf);
}

.links{
     font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

for some reason it's not working though. I know the css for .links is working though cause I have other stuff in there and it works but for some reason font-family isn't working.

Comment: Is the font-url inside the `src` tag correct?

Comment: You are misisng the `'` to enclose the font name in src and family... don't follow w3 schools better follow this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Based on your code, it appears that it's trying to load the .ttf from the same directory that the CSS is in. Is that correct?

Comment: The above comments are sure worth checking and might solve your problem. I would like to add that it's a good practice to add alternative woff font files. Since not all browser support tff fonts especially when you take a look at mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Add "fonts" folder, then link it:

```
   @font-face {
  font-family: Simp; 
  src: local('Simplifica Regular'), local('Simplifica'); 
  /* Check how the font is written on the machine --> Right click on file -> Details -> Title */ 
  src: url(/fonts/simplifica.ttf) format('truetype'); 
  font-weight: normal;}
```

Hope this helps.